# Passing ssl certificates paths to PostgreSQL ODBC driver

Tags: postgresql, odbc

I'm attempting to connect to a Postgres database that requires the client pass the paths to client and server SSL certificates using the ODBC driver for postgres. I'm using `psqlodbc` v11 x86 on Windows 10. I need to have three options passed to the ODBC driver `sslrootcert`, `sslcert`, and `sslkey`. I know that the paths are not being passed by the odbc driver since when I connect using the following connection string where I specify the `pqopts` it is able to connect.

`Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE};Server=XXXX;Port=5432;Database=XXXX;Uid=XXXX;Pwd=XXX;sslmode=verify-ca;pqopt={sslrootcert=C:\\ssl\\pgSQL.ca.cert sslcert=C:\\ssl\\pgSQL.cert sslkey=C:\\ssl\\pgSQL.key}`

According to the document section 
[**Advanced Options 3/3 Dialog Box**->**Libpq parameters**](https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/config.html), I should be able to pass the parameters by typing the values within the braces directly into the text box. It displays the error message saying that it cannot find the certificate because it is looking in the default location and is not using the value that was provided in the `Libpq` text box. Am I doing something wrong? Any advise on how to connect passing client certificates would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Setting parameters]

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 2):

Answering this in case anyone else finds this useful. The problem seems to be that the Test button on the ODBC Driver doesn't take the options set in the libpq parameters into account and just uses the default settings. When I saved the ODBC connection closed the ODBC Data Source Administrator window and used the connection from a different program it was able to connect successfully.